# Number of real roots of a quintic polynomial

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, roots, rolles-theorem

> Obtain the number of real roots of the following quintic polynomial $$f(x)= x^5+x^3-2x+1$$

My approach:

First, on seeing the polynomial, it should be clear that it is continuous. Also, $f(-\infty)=-\infty$ and $f(\infty)=\infty$. Hence, the function has at least one root. Now, the derivative is calculated as:

$$f'(x)=5x^4+3x^2-2$$

which gives the two solutions as $\pm\sqrt{\frac25}$. Now, we need to test for the roots in each of the intervals. In the first Interval, the value of function is negative at $-\infty$ and positive at $-\sqrt{\frac25}$. Hence, function will have one root in this interval. Then, in the second Interval function decreases but never touches $x$-axis as it takes positive value at $\sqrt{\frac25}$. Also, the function again start to increase in the third Interval and is positive at $\infty$. Hence, it has only one root.

Is my approach correct? My textbook gives the answer 3 using Rolle's theorem. It says that since the $f'(x)$ has two roots, then $f(x)$ will have three roots using Rolle's theorem. Thanks.

Comment: [According to WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5%2Bx%5E3-2x%2B1%3D0) , there is only one real root: your book is wrong.

Comment: Since $f'(x)$ has two roots, by Rolle's theorem $f(x)$ cannot have _more_ than three roots. But whether the answer is one, two or three roots the theorem cannot tell you.

Comment: @Arthur, thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is correct, and the textbook misses the point. There is no direct relation between the number of zeros of $f'(x)$ and the number of zeros of $f(x)$, since derivatives ignore constant terms and (dually) integrals are only defined up to a constant.

(The number of zeros of $f'(x)$ plus one is an upper bound for the number of roots of $f(x)$, but the latter may go all the way down to zero, as pointed out in the comments on this answer.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was really confused in this.

Comment: There is a relation between the number of roots of the derivative and the *upper* bound of the number of roots of the original function, but not between the derivative and the *lower* bound.

Answer (score 8):

Your approach is OK.  Here is just another way.

By Descartes' rule of signs, $f(-x) = -x^5-x^3+2x+1$ has exactly one sign change, so there is exactly one negative real root.

As $f(x) = x^5+x^3-2x+1$ itself has two sign changes, we can have either no or two positive roots.  We are left to show there is none, which can be observed by the following AM-GM:
$$f(x) = x^5 + x^3 + 6\times \tfrac16 - 2x \geqslant \frac8{\sqrt[8]{6^6}}x -2x > 0$$
as $8 > 2\cdot 6^{3/4} \iff 4^4 > 6^3 \iff 256 > 216$ which is true.

Comment: Your method is unique. Nice. Thank you so much.